# Wrong calculation while using a form and a function in html and Java

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with the code below. I am trying to calculate the time someone is allowed to drive after consuming alcohol. The formula is: Amount of alcohol * 1.25 (for a man) or 1.5 (for a woman) + time of the last consumed glass of alcohol = driveTime.

The problem is that the formula makes a calulation with "1" instead of "1.25" or "1.5".

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks! Kaspar

HTML:

```
<li>What is your sex?<SELECT NAME="sexItem"  id="sexItem"></li>
    <OPTION value="1.25">Male</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="1.50">Female</OPTION>
```

```
<button type="button" onclick="calculateTime()">Calculate</button>

<p>You are able to drive at:<INPUT type="text" id="driveTime" Size=1>o'clock.</p>
```

JS:

```
var elt = document.getElementById("sexItem");
var sex = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

//calculate total value  
var total = amount*sex+time; 

//print value to driveTime 
document.getElementById("driveTime").value=total;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parseFloat function for the values returned for 'sex' is a string:

```
var sex = parseFloat(elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value);
```